# Automatically raised flags

Tags: support

I only rarely review raised flags as they are handled lightning-fast by the moderators. But as I have done so lately, I have seen this:

[image]

which has aroused my curiosity. *"Low answer quality score [81], /questions/how-to-answer shown and skipped"* looks like an automated flag and I would like to know

- how the quality score is calculated (would this somehow be connected to the "low-quality" review queue?)
- what automated flags are raised by the system

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an automated flag. The scoring system is secret sauce, but time spent on the page, length, and jargon content affect the score (probably other things too).

I think that's the only system generated flag that you can see/review. There is only one other that I'm aware of, it's tripped when a user starts building a negative track record for themself.

Comment: I see, secret sauce again. I want stackexchangeleaks.org now!